# How to delete entries from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm exploring the functions of Firebase, I'm having trouble on how to delete nodes or entries from firebase using java code ? I searched their API .. the web version does provide remove() function, but the java doesn't ?!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a `removeValue()` method on the `Firebase` object:

[Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_removeValue)

Setting a location's value to `null` essentially removes the node from the structure.

Comment: nulling a value comes in very handy for ensuring multiple deletes on different paths due to denormalizing  your DB.

Answer (score 4):

Although @jsfrocha answer is totally correct it is important to note that if you're using transactions, which is a good practice when you're deleting data, you access the data through a MutableData object in which case you don't have the the `removeValue(...)` method so you should use `setValue(null)` instead.

Here is a snipped ...

```
firebase.child(path).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        mutableData.setValue(null); // This removes the node.
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError error, boolean b, DataSnapshot data) {
        // Handle completion
    }
});
```