# How to delete comment from Firebase and from my app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a simple comment box where someone can enter a username and a comment and it is written to the database.

What I am trying to do right now is create a cross by that comment so that the user can delete it. However I am not to sure how to do this.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, or some tutorials would be great?

Code:

```
fireBaseRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    // // store all current comments from firebase
    var fbData = snapshot.val()
```

Comment: Or maybe even trying to use $(this).parent().remove();  , however i am not to sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete entries from firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647506/how-to-delete-entries-from-firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the keys of each comment you get from the Firebase in the child_added event handler.

```
fireBaseRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key();
    });
});
```

When a comment has to be deleted later you can do so by using it's key.

```
fireBaseRef.child(key).remove(function(error) {
    alert(error ? "Error" : "Success");
});
```

Alternatively you can also get a reference when you push to Firebase like this.

```
var pushedRef = ref.push({test: "true"});
```

You can then delete the data at this reference.

```
pushedRef.remove(function(error) {
    alert(error ? "Error" : "Success");
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, so this would work , with the user just clicking on the x to delete the comment?

Comment: Because that is the bit i cant seem to get to work at all

Comment: i have posted my html ontop is well to help if that makes it easier